# Restart Unix service

Tags: java, ubuntu, process, runtime.exec

I have Ubuntu in my machine where I have installed snmpd. To start stop I use below command:

1. service snmpd start
2. service snmpd stop

Now I have to execute this comments from java. I have tried with but it does not work.

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exe("service snmpd start")
```

So, could you tell me how to execute a service of Linux suse through java?

Any help would be great

Comment: No, that's not what you tried. That doesn't even compile!

Comment: *"Any help would be great"*  Any question would be helpful.

Comment: Please read [this article on `Runtime.exec()`](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). It's old, but it's still true (except that you could replace `Runtime.exec()` with `ProcessBuilder`, which has a nicer API, but still has the same pits to fall into).

Comment: @AndrewThompson: rarely have I seen an article on an actual API (as opposed to "a concept") that has aged so well.

Comment: @JoachimSauer  Too true.  There might be lots of good articles on JavaWorld, but that is the only one I have book-marked. :)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I don't even have it bookmarked. I google "Runtime exec won't" and click on the first hit ;-)

Comment: @JoachimSauer OK I'll fess up.  When I said 'book-marked' I actually meant it is in a little utility I wrote over the last few days that stores my most common comments.  It is just a matter of selecting comments (shown in a `JTable`) that fit a question, then copying the resulting string into a comment.  I quite like it already..  :)  OK, I can see how Google would work as well.  ;)

Comment: Huh.  An edit & the question **still** contains a code snippet that would not compile..  :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suddenly people started talking about a link instead of the question. The solution is easy. One need to wait for the process to complete. See below code.

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("service snmpd start");
process.waitFor();
```